# Scope and SQL query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In app/controllers/ElementTypesController.rb, I have this:

```
l = params[:element_type_name]
@element_types = ElementType.by_name(l).page(params[:page])
```

and in the model app/models/ElementType.rb, I have this:

```
scope :by_name, (lambda do |name| { :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%"]} end )
```

However, this throws an error, complaining that pagination (Kaminari) can't happen on a hash. What is wrong with my scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4 you should use other syntax for declare SQL conditions (look at `where` method):

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) { where('name LIKE ?', "%#{name}%") }
```

So, you have `can't happen on a hash` because Rails 4 doesn't recognize this syntax anymore. It has been deprecated.

Comment: this won't work, your scope is not taking parameter!

Comment: @maxd and Sharvy Ahmed, I used a fix to Max's answer, and it works. scope :by_name ->(name) { where... }  Why does this work, whereas my previous approach didn't work?  Thanks to both of you for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe scope is just an alias, so its also possible to do it like this

```
def self.by_name (name)
   where('name LIKE ?', "%#{name}")
end
```